# How to bring future days to past date and then revert to same old days using postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, psql

I have a db with 6 tables. Each table has a list of `date` and `datetime` columns as shown below

```
Table 1                Table 2              ....               Table 6

Date_of_birth          Exam_date  exam_datetime               Result_date   Result_datetime

2190-01-13             2192-01-13  2192-01-13 09:00:00        2194-04-13    2194-04-13 07:12:00
2184-05-21             2186-05-21  2186-05-21 07:00:00        2188-02-03    2188-02-03 09:32:00
2181-06-17             2183-06-17  2183-06-17 05:00:00        2185-07-23    2185-07-23 12:40:00
```

What I would like to do is shift all these future days back to the past date (definitely has to be less than the current date) but retain the same chronological order. Meaning, we can see that the person was born first, then he took the exam, and finally, he got his results.

In addition, I should be able to revert the changes and get back the future dates again.

I expect my output to be something like below

Stage 1 - shift back to old days (it can be any day but it has to be in the past and retain chronological order)

```
Table 1                Table 2              ....               Table 6

Date_of_birth          Exam_date  exam_datetime               Result_date   Result_datetime

1990-01-13             1992-01-13  1992-01-13 09:00:00        1994-04-13    1994-04-13 07:12:00
1984-05-21             1986-05-21  1986-05-21 07:00:00        1988-02-03    1988-02-03 09:32:00
1981-06-17             1983-06-17  1983-06-17 05:00:00        1985-07-23    1985-07-23 12:40:00
```

Stage 2 - Shift forward to future days as how it was earlier

```
Table 1                Table 2              ....               Table 6

Date_of_birth          Exam_date  exam_datetime               Result_date   Result_datetime

2190-01-13             2192-01-13  2192-01-13 09:00:00        2194-04-13    2194-04-13 07:12:00
2184-05-21             2186-05-21  2186-05-21 07:00:00        2188-02-03    2188-02-03 09:32:00
2181-06-17             2183-06-17  2183-06-17 05:00:00        2185-07-23    2185-07-23 12:40:00
```

Comment: Where is your attempt? You've got 3,257xp, surely you would you have to give it a go first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract two centuries:

```
update table1
    set date_of_birth = date_of_birth - interval '200 year';
```

You can do something similar for all the other dates.

Comment: Later, I can again just add `200 years`. Right? Thanks for the help. upvoted

Comment: @TheGreat . . . Yes, that should work.  The only nuance is that it might be off for leap years if the difference is not a leap year.  I don't think that will happen until . . . Feb 29th, 2400.